# Change text of a button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a board that contains 9 small boards and each small board contains 9 cells (Ultimate TicTacToe).
i'm trying to use the click function and print "x" on the clicked button but it doesnt change the text of the button and i dont have an idea why.
please help me.
here is the code:

```
    <script>
        var bigTable = "<table align='center' value='bigBoard' border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'\><tbody>";
        for (var k = 0; k < 9; k++) 
        {
            if (k % 3 === 0)
            {
                bigTable += "<tr>";
            }

            bigTable += "<td>";
            var mytable = "<table value='smallBoard'+k border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'><tbody><tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    var position = +k + "," + j + "," + i;
                    mytable += "<td><button class='a' id=" + position + " type='submit' name=" + position + "></button</td>";
                }

                mytable += "</tr><tr>";
            }

            mytable += "</tr></tbody></table>";
            bigTable += mytable + "</td>";

            if (k % 3 === 2)
            {
                bigTable += "</tr>";
            }
        }

        bigTable += "</tbody></table>";
        document.write(bigTable);
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".a").click(function() {
            var buttonPressed = $(this).attr("id");
                jQuery.ajax({
                        data:buttonPressed,
                        url:"board",
                        success: function(responseText){
                            //alert("acac" + buttonPressed);
                            $("#" + buttonPressed).text(responseText);

                        }
                   }); 
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `responseText`? Is your ajax success handler ever hit?

Comment: thw value of responseText is 'x'

Comment: if i change the  
$("#" + buttonPressed).text(responseText)
to
$(".a").text(responseText)... a is the class then it prints on all cells

Comment: the servlet is 
out.print('x');

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is the value of `buttonPressed` getting assigned correctly?

Comment: you tried what I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are doing wrong, change this:

> var position = +k + "," + j + "," + i;

to something like,

> var position = +k + "-" + j + "-" + i;

Answer (score 0):

Change the *type* of button from **submit** to **button** because you are calling Ajax request, not submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this jsfiddle and it works fine 
Try it

http://jsfiddle.net/P8wrb/1/

Just declare a variable for your clicked button and then set the .text for it by reference

```
$(".a").click(function() {
     var that = $(this);
     ....
     that.text('X'); 
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I think the issue was in the buttonPressed was incorrectly assigned.